# How can I use ClickHouse's `with <constant> as <alias>` syntax from Knex?

Tags: knex.js, clickhouse

We have a TypeScript application where we use Knex for all of our database interactions. We mostly use PostgreSQL, but for some perf-related stuff, we're running against a ClickHouse cloud instance, which we connect to from Knex via the MySQL2 protocol handler. ClickHouse has a nice constant-aliasing syntax via `with <constant> as <alias>` syntax (example 1 [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/with#examples). I'd like to use this from knex, but I can't figure out a stable way to construct it via built-in knex stuff.

I tried inverting the parameters to `QueryBuilder.with`, but it escaped the constant with backticks like an identifier and put the actual identifier inside of parentheses, both of which didn't work.

Eg: `knex.with('blahblah', 'my_name')` becomes

```
with `blahblah` as ('my_name')
```

The other thing I can think of doing is something like:

```
query = knex.raw(`with <constant value> as my_constant_identifier`, query);
```

I'm pretty sure I can make this work, but it's really brittle in terms of the code to the point that testing this in my app is non-trival.